# Rewards for the best answer from the 2nd quarter of 2017

Tags: discussion, answers, scheduled-event

Inspired by the mods of a few other communities, this is a continuation of a series of quarterly rewards for the best answer, and I'd ask the community for the best answers from the past quarter to get an additional reward:

**Please link to an answer which was created from April 1st 2017 through June 30th 2017 and which you think deserves an additional reward. Only one entry per answer will be valid. For multiple favorites submit separate answers to this post.**

Here is a data query to help with the decision making process:

- **[Answers with most votes from 2nd quarter of 2017](http://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/edit/689086)**

If your answer isn't linked on the list above, no problem! You are free to choose your own favorite answer which didn't get the limelight. Any nominated answer can be from you or from someone else.

The highest voted answer of this meta post will be picked up for the reward of 200 points after 2 weeks.

Note: Answer must have 1+ upvote and submitted in the same quarter only. Answer should not be a wiki. Please only propose one post in any answer here so the votes can easily be tallied.

**SHOUT OUT** to [@DerekF](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/24889/derek-f) for contributing some of his hard earned points last quarter to further increase the rewards pool! Thanks!

Comment: Locking this post to prevent future votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always enjoy profiling questions, so here's one: [How can you benchmark Apex code to determine what operations consume the most CPU time?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/167757/2995).

It's pretty awesome to see folks using a package I developed! I need to publish some of the improvements I have been working on... anyway it's far from complete but I like that this answer gets people thinking about the question of performance. It's obviously a topic I find compelling.

Comment: Great answer and also using the package developed by our moderator. Awesome ! We need a place which references all the awesome packages !

Answer (score 6):

I like Rahul's answer on [Maintain unique user name in Test methods?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/173492/2995)

Talk about unlikely collisions! It is also sound advice to move code for test data creation into utility methods. All of the answers to this question offer sound advice, must have been tough to choose which to accept.

Answer (score 3):

I like this question and answer.

Got some undocumented stuff on testing an asynchronous code, using `Test.stopTest()` from @sfdcfox's answer.

[@future runs in test without Test.stopTest() - Can that be?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173723/future-runs-in-test-without-test-stoptest-can-that-be/173734#173734)

Comment: The preciseness and quality of answer makes its very good. All of Sfdcfox's answers are very good :) but i like this one better.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to nominate Caspar's answer on [Different return types of a class method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174495/different-return-types-of-a-class-method) as being clear and helpful for the less skilled and experienced programmers here.